# Simplifying a logical expression with multivariate polynomials

Tags: simplifying-expressions, polynomials, inequalities, logic

I have several expressions similar to

```
a (a b + c d) != 0 || b (a b + c d) != 0 || c (a b + c d) != 0 || d (a b + c d) != 0
```

and I would like to reduce them maximally; in the above example, the given logical statement is clearly just equivalent to `a b + c d != 0`, but how to arrive at this?

Both `Reduce` and `Resolve`, as well as `FullSimplify` return it unchanged. I tried

```
BooleanConvert[
  (a != 0 && a b + c d != 0) ||
  (b != 0 && a b + c d != 0) ||
  (c != 0 && a b + c d != 0) ||
  (d != 0 && a b + c d != 0)
  , "CNF"
]
```

but it stops at

```
(a != 0 || b != 0 || c != 0 || d != 0) && a b + c d != 0
```

Is there a way?

Comment: If we know the required result, then `Resolve[ForAll[{a, b, c, d}, 
  Equivalent[(a != 0 && a  b + c  d != 0) || (b != 0 && 
      a  b + c  d != 0) || (c != 0 && a  b + c  d != 0) || (d != 0 && 
      a  b + c  d != 0), a  b + c  d != 0]]]` confirms it by `True`.

Comment: @user64494 Thank you, this is important information. So it definitly should be doable in Mathematica somehow.

Comment: A possible reason for non-simplification could be that `FullSimplify[(a != 0 || b != 0) && a b != 0]` simplifies to `a b != 0`, whereas `FullSimplify[(a != 0 || b != 0) && a + b != 0]` does not simplify to `a + b != 0`

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

"14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)"

Clear["Global`*"]

expr = a  (a  b + c  d) != 0 || b  (a  b + c  d) != 0 || 
   c  (a  b + c  d) != 0 || d  (a  b + c  d) != 0;
```

Tell Mathematica that the variables are boolean

```
Assuming[{a, b, c, d} ∈ Booleans, expr // Simplify]

(* a b + c d != 0 *)
```

Comment: The variables are not assumed to be `Boolean`, or at least this is not stated and also not a necessary assumption for the desired simplification to hold.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Actually I need it for complex numbers - or for that matter for any field...

Answer (score 2):

The following is a very manual approach, but might be informative

```
expr = a (a b + c d) != 0 || b (a b + c d) != 0 || 
   c (a b + c d) != 0 || d (a b + c d) != 0;
```

Considering the negation of the expression feels more natural

```
Simplify[! expr]
(* 
a (a b + c d) == 0 && b (a b + c d) == 0 && c (a b + c d) == 0 && 
 d (a b + c d) == 0 *)
```

Employing an obvious rule

```
x_ y_ == 0 :> x == 0 || y == 0;

%% /. %
(* (a == 0 || a b + c d == 0) && (b == 0 || 
   a b + c d == 0) && (c == 0 || a b + c d == 0) && (d == 0 || 
   a b + c d == 0) *)
```

We get a simple expression

```
negative = FullSimplify[%]
(* (a == 0 && b == 0 && c == 0 && d == 0) || a b + c d == 0 *)
```

The following implication is obviously true

```
implication = Implies[First[negative], Last[negative]]
(* 
a == 0 && b == 0 && c == 0 && d == 0 \[Implies] a b + c d == 0 *)
```

Mathematica but doesn't recognise this implication as true, but can recognise its negative as false

```
! FullSimplify[! implication]
(* True *)
```

Combining the implication and the statement we get

```
! (implication && negative) // BooleanConvert
(* a b + c d != 0 *)
```

Comment: I believe this same observation (or rather its equivalent without negation) was made by @user64494 in a comment to the question. This, I believe, shows that potentially Mathematica can do it without the hint too somehow.